# Connect to HornetQ from another system

Tags: hornetq

I run a HornetQ in standalone mode with its default configuration and I can connect to it from local system, If I want to connect from another system which configurations must be changed to make this possible?!

Comment: You should edit your question and add some context on what you mean by other system. the question is a bit dubious. what's a full plate for negative votes to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to define what you mean by another system, did you mean another HornetQ instance, or did you mean another JMS Server?

What's the connection medium? you want a Bridge between hornetQ and other JMS Systems? look at the JMS Bridge on the hornetQ documentation

You want a client to connect to different Message servers? look at the Stomp protocol and several clients available from apache / activeMQ guys. HOrnetQ supports Stomp natively on the server's side.

Comment: The problem is not so complicated, I want to run HornetQ on one system as a server and all other clients connect to the server and pass messages on different queues which has been defined on server

Comment: You're just explaining simple client & server communication which is a simple thing on HornetQ.

you should read this chapter:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Alpha/docs/user-manual/html/configuring-transports.html

Comment: Yes, But only client from localhost can connect to HornetQ and if I run client in another system it can't connect to server

Comment: I get this exception:
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 0.0.0.0; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: You can't connect to 0.0.0.0, the connector has to be on a real IP. Use real IPs

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure transports, Netty transports.

Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.14.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#configuring-transports

Answer (score 0):

These are my configurations

hornetq-configuration.xml:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">
   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty-connector">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="port" value="5446"/>
      </connector>
   </connectors>
   <acceptors>
      <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">
     <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
     <param key="port" value="5446"/>
     <param key="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
      </acceptor>
   </acceptors>
</configuration>
```

hornetq-beans.xml:

```
<bean name="Naming" class="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl"/>
<bean name="JNDIServer" class="org.jnp.server.Main">
  <property name="namingInfo">
     <inject bean="Naming"/>
  </property>
  <property name="port">1099</property>
  <property name="bindAddress">0.0.0.0</property>
  <property name="rmiPort">1098</property>
  <property name="rmiBindAddress">0.0.0.0</property>
</bean>
```